# SpecsFor MVC - Can't get site to build / appear

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, selenium

I am attempting to create some UI tests using SpecsFor MVC, I am coming at this from a new user's point of view in terms of testing so could be easily missing something obvious.

The site I'm testing against already uses it's own test DB so I do not need to create one. when I build and debug normally on this site it also starts up a couple of WCF projects which we use for service layer interactions. Presumably I'll need to start these in the specs config but have not got that far yet.

I've followed the documentation and have created this method:

```
 protected override void AfterConfigurationApplied()
        {
            var config = new SpecsForMvcConfig();
            config.UseIISExpress()
                .With(Project.Named("TestSite"))
                .UsePort(55555)
                .CleanupPublishedFiles()
                .UseMSBuildExecutableAt(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe");

            config.BuildRoutesUsing(MvcApplication.RegisterRoutes);

            config.UseBrowser(BrowserDriver.Chrome);

            _host = new SpecsForIntegrationHost(config);
            _host.Start();
        }
```

The routing of the site is set in the Global.asax hence the setting in the above method.
I also have this very basic test in place to just see if I can get it working:

```
 protected override void When()
            {
                SUT.NavigateTo<HomeController>(u => u.Index());
                SUT.FindLinkTo<HomeController>(u => u.About())
                    .Click();

            }
```

When I debug the tests it successfully starts Chrome but hangs for ages and eventually fails with this error:

OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:49924/session/bd15d6a15395b4ca204437c340639501/element timed out after 60 seconds.

I'm not sure where that port number or session etc are coming from.

If I'm running my web project normally (outside of this whole testing project) I see a URL like this:

https://localhost:55555

I would have thought I'd see something similar for these tests cases? It doesn't really matter in any case because they're not working.

Am I missing some element of the config? Do I need to set up the WCF layer to run as well?

Comment: It sounds like something isn't getting wired up correctly.  That error usually means it can't even talk to Selenium's WebDriver... can you submit a repro case at the official Github repo?  If so, I can take a look at it and see if I can reproduce it.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for replying. I got it to work eventually but I think the issue is more with how our dev environment is configured. It runs but not every time, most times I get the above error and have to restart my IISexpress to get it working again.